# Segfault after creating instance of model in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, libgosu

I have the following model in my Rails application:

```
class Window < Gosu::Window

  def initialize
    super( 250, 100, false )
    @background_image = Gosu::Image.new( self, 'hello.png' )
  end

  def draw
    @background_image.draw( 0, 0, 1 )
  end

  def button_down(id)
    close
  end
end
```

As you can see, the model is basically a "hello world" for launching a Gosu library window. I got the idea off "[Ruby Tips #336 – Turn Rails into a Game Engine](http://brettu.com/rails-ruby-tips-336-turn-rails-into-a-game-engine/)". The problem begins when I do the following:

```
$ rails console

2.2.1 :001> win = Window.new
```

Immediately after I press enter I get a segmentation fault with the following stack trace:

```
/Users/giancarloguerra/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Users/giancarloguerra/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Users/giancarloguerra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.4.4/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/giancarloguerra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.4.4/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
/Users/giancarloguerra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.4.4/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
/Users/giancarloguerra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.4.4/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
/Users/giancarloguerra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.4.4/lib/spring/application.rb:156:in `serve'
/Users/giancarloguerra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.4.4/lib/spring/application.rb:156:in `fork'
/Users/giancarloguerra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.4.4/lib/spring/application.rb:183:in `block in serve'
/Users/giancarloguerra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.4.4/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:38:in `call'
/Users/giancarloguerra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.4.4/lib/spring/commands/rails.rb:6:in `call'
/Users/giancarloguerra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/Users/giancarloguerra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/Users/giancarloguerra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
/Users/giancarloguerra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/Users/giancarloguerra/Desktop/testgosu/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/giancarloguerra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/Users/giancarloguerra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/Users/giancarloguerra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/Users/giancarloguerra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/Users/giancarloguerra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/giancarloguerra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
/Users/giancarloguerra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
/Users/giancarloguerra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
/Users/giancarloguerra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
/Users/giancarloguerra/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb.rb:394:in `start'
/Users/giancarloguerra/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb.rb:394:in `catch'
/Users/giancarloguerra/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb.rb:395:in `block in start'
/Users/giancarloguerra/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb.rb:485:in `eval_input'
/Users/giancarloguerra/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:230:in `each_top_level_statement'
/Users/giancarloguerra/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:230:in `catch'
/Users/giancarloguerra/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:231:in `block in each_top_level_statement'
/Users/giancarloguerra/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:231:in `loop'
/Users/giancarloguerra/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:245:in `block (2 levels) in each_top_level_statement'
/Users/giancarloguerra/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb.rb:486:in `block in eval_input'
/Users/giancarloguerra/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb.rb:623:in `signal_status'
/Users/giancarloguerra/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb.rb:489:in `block (2 levels) in eval_input'
/Users/giancarloguerra/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb/context.rb:379:in `evaluate'
/Users/giancarloguerra/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb/workspace.rb:86:in `evaluate'
/Users/giancarloguerra/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb/workspace.rb:86:in `eval'
(irb):1:in `irb_binding'
(irb):1:in `new'
/Users/giancarloguerra/Desktop/testgosu/app/models/window.rb:5:in `initialize'
/Users/giancarloguerra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/gosu-0.10.4/lib/gosu/swig_patches.rb:19:in `initialize'
/Users/giancarloguerra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/gosu-0.10.4/lib/gosu/swig_patches.rb:19:in `initialize'
```

Along with information on the loaded features from the console. In the end, the console tells me that I may have found a bug and that I should report it.

Here's what I have done about it:

1. Checked gosu gem is installed. It is.
2. Debugged my program.
3. Followed the stack trace for any remote clues.

I'm all out of ideas here. Any suggestions as to what could be happening? I appreciate your help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't add "Ruby on Rails" or other tags to your title. If you can work them in naturally that's OK, but the title should read like a sentence.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing those out. .

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the 'Spring' gem was causing the issues. After I removed that, the window executed :)